# How to post and get data uri image from web api?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post data uri image from javascript to backend asp.net webapi. However, it gives me `input is not a valid Base-64 string` error. Now, I understand that it may be due to "data:image/png;base64," part that the data uri contain.

Now, even if I remove this part from the data uri and send only the rest of the string to server, how do I store the Base-64 string on the server?

Moreover, how to retrieve this data as image from webapi?

**NOTE:** Image would be less than 200kB size and hence is to be stored as varbinary(Max) in sql server.

Comment: If it's a base 64 **string**, why not store it in a varchar column?

Comment: @stuartd So, then I would retrieve the data as string and add the 'data:image/png;base64,' part to the string in javascript right?

Is there an easier way where I don't have to manipulate string?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is you should convert your image to byte[] and store it in your server as varbinary

```
 byte []arr = new byte[image1.ContentLength];
 image1.InputStream.Read(arr, 0, image1.ContentLength);
```

While retrieving you should convert the varbinary data to base64 string and base 64 string to image

```
string imageBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(img);
```

Here comes the important part the above code convert varbinary to base64string.It should be in proper format to display the image.Thats what the following code does

```
  string imageDataURL = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", asd);
  Session["Photo"] = imageDataURL;
```

Now you can able to view your image

Answer (score 0):

Post the image from your client in a for of string, w/o specifying the type. On your action you can get the image in the following way :

```
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(yourStringHere);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
```

Comment: And then? Should the image be stored as varbinary? And how to get this image from webapi?

Comment: You can store it as varchar(MAX). What do you mean how to get it from the webapi ? If you post it from the client as a GET/POST request with a parameter, then you can put a parameter in your action with the same name(if it comes from POST you need [FromBody] attribute).

Comment: What I am asking is how would the http get method look like? Assuming one image would be 50kB in size. Should pagination be used? Moreover, I think caching would be necessary, right?